# How can i import the document in Llamaindex

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, llama-index

I am trying to work with llama index and constantly i coming across the error of loading the document.
#Load and index the data with the simpleDirectoryReader of Llama Index
reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./modals/llamaindex test/data/paul_graham_essay.txt"])
docs = readr.load_data()
print(f"Loaded{len(docs)}docs") this is my code.
[Basically the error says document is not in the desired location and dont know the exact reason why is it so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9BI.png)

I am trying to provide the llama index with the document and then ask question regarding that. I am strictly following the website and completely new with this AI and coding.